# Unify 'datetime' format of data

Tags: r, datetime, xts, zoo

Due to errors in my database/export, I have an inconsistant timestamp - sometimes with seconds, sometimes without - how can I easily unify it?

e.g. read_csv with `X1 = col_datetime(format = "%d.%m.%Y %H:%M:%S")` is not working properly.

My data look like follows:

```
X1, X2
24.02.2012 22:00, '121'
24.02.2012 22:15:00, '122'
24.02.2012 22:30:00, '124'
24.02.2012 22:45:00, '122'
24.02.2012 23:00, '121'
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`anytime` can handle it with an additional format entry (as d.m.Y can be confused with m.d.Y we do not add it by default, by entering it you make a more conscious choice).

```
> times <- c("24.02.2012 22:00", "24.02.2012 22:15:00", "24.02.2012 22:30:00", 
+            "24.02.2012 22:45:00", "24.02.2012 23:00") 
> library(anytime)  
> addFormats("%d.%m.%Y %H:%M:%S")       
> anytime(times)      
[1] "2012-02-24 22:00:00 CST" "2012-02-24 22:15:00 CST" "2012-02-24 22:30:00 CST"
+   "2012-02-24 22:45:00 CST" "2012-02-24 23:00:00 CST"     
>
```

So you could overwrite your column, or add a new ones, via

```
> library(anytime)  
> addFormats("%d.%m.%Y %H:%M:%S")       
> X1$parsed <- anytime(X1$raw_dates)
```

(assuming you have the data in `X` in that column) after adding the format as shown. Formats are added to the vector of known
formats only for the current session.